# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am getting the error in the code igniter view page as

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() codeigniter in the following code;

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?=$page_title?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php foreach($result as $row):?>
    <h3><?=$row->title?></h3>
    <p><?=$row->text?></p>
    <br />
    <?php endforeach;?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Test the `$result` if it is an array, before using foreach on it. Your result may be `false` since your database query failed, or returned no result.

```
if (is_array($result))
{
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$result` is not an array at all.

You should check the `$result` construction code. you are not setting `$result` properly.

If `$result` is supposed to hold database rows, checkout the database query if that is returning result properly.

Comment: @jeni: "give the codes" is *exactly* the wrong attitude for this website. It is favorable if you do some of the thinking yourself.